# Nagios Supervisor status check

Tags: nagios

I want to check my supervisord status by nagios.I haven 2 servers 1 nagios and other is client server.In my client server supervisor is running.
  I have put my check_supervisord.py file in my /usr/local/nagios/libexec path & on my services.cfg file:

```
   define service {
   use generic-service
   host_name ubuntuserver
   service_description supervisord
   check_command check_supervisord!80!hduser!password
                  }
```

But it showing me plugin missing error,

[image]

Comment: What is the entry for commands.cfg?

Answer (score 1):

Since your other plugins are successfully running I would guess this is a permission issue.

```
cd /usr/local/nagios/libexec
chmod 755 check_supervisord.py
chown root:nagios check_supervisord.py
```

Try that and see if the plugin works.  If this doesn't work try and see what permissions supervisord needs to run in a script or compare the script permissions to the other plugins that are working on your system.